# Change SwiftUI ProgressView Color - macOS not iOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am attempting to create a white ProgressView spinner on macOS using SwiftUI / Swift 5.2 using:

```
ProgressView()
    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.white))
    .accentColor(Color.white)
```

However this does not seem to change the color. I have googled and searched but cannot figure how to change the color.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of iOS 15 it seems like your code works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.white))
            .padding()
            .background(.black)
    }
}
```

Note that [`.tint(Color.white)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tint(_:)) also works, but the deprecated [`.accentColor(Color.white)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accentcolor(_:)) does not.

[image: White spinner on black background]

I'm pretty sure back in iOS 14 `progressViewStyle` had no effect on indeterminate spinners, so for a more backwards-compatible version try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .colorInvert() /// make the spinner a semi-opaque white
            .brightness(1) /// ramp up the brightness
            .padding()
            .background(.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and correct however, I'm really just looking for an indeterminate progress indicator... I just need it to be white.. any thoughts on how I might do that? I just want it to come up when my app is processing login / api calls etc. Some of them can take a second or two and I want folks to know its doing stuff.

Comment: That will do it in this case. I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Note that `.colorScheme(...)` has been deprecated and was replaced with `.preferredColorScheme(...)`

Comment: Unfortunately `preferredColorScheme` sets the color scheme of the entire app to dark/light mode.

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked on macOS, which as of this time, 12.3.1 ignores the .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.white))

Comment: It seems the Previews are not working for macOS, Xcode 14, but running the app shows the color set for the ProgressView.tint(newColor)